# Integrating java program and wordpress website

Tags: java, wordpress, jsp, servlets

I developed a tool in Java and a website in Wordpress. Now I want to put my Java tool online. The tool performs a computation based on some user input. The situation I want to achieve is that the user can input the data required for the tool on a specific page of my website and the java tool will output the solution on that same page.

I don't know much about web development but I read some articles about Servlets, JSP, Web Containers (like Tomcat). Do I have to rewrite my website in JSP now? Or is there also a way to "integrate a Java Servlet in an existing website (in my case developed with Wordpress)?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you iFrame in the application on your Wordpress site?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269153/a-blog-engine-to-integrate-with-a-java-app-which-blog-engine

Answer (score 0):

If the process is expected to be short-lived, you may be best off by running it like a regular Java command line program in a process, capturing stdout and stderr.  No need to set up a java container like Tomcat.